# Similarity matrix and multiple-regression

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance, gaussian-process

Let, $S_{n*n}$ represent a similarity matrix, among $n$ observation, my case n = 215. and $Y=\{y_1, y_2, ...,y_n\}$ contains a response value for each $x_n$ observation. For each observation we have $t$ features,my case t = 50.

Since, the number of observation is not enough vs features to do a nice multiply regression, I am wondering, if there is any clever way to use that Similarity matrix !

I had an idea, which I would like to add,
I was thinking that, for each test data $x^*$, I can look at my training similarity matrix,$S$ and take, say top 10 high similar observation $X_{top10}$, and try to guess $y^*$ for my test data ${x^*}$, from those 10 observation only.

Theoretically, it makes a lot of scenes, due to similar observations are ending up at similar response values, but the problem is how to make that regression and also identify most predictive features.

Comment: I used the similarity matrix as co-variance matrix inside Gaussian Process.